# Google sheet dynamic tab selection

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet where in one tab I have column (A2:A10) of names, A, B, C etc.
For some of the names I have a tab that have the same name and others I don't.

I what to have make a range like
{indirect($A$2&"!d8:g8");indirect($A$3&"!d8:g8"),..}
but where I have a mach between the name column and the tab name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each range should be protected against error messages that occur when range does not exist.
The problem is that error message is just one cell and you need 4 cells for each row to have valid range.

So my solution is to make for each row:

```
iferror(indirect($A$2&"!d8:g8"),{"","","",""});
iferror(indirect($A$3&"!d8:g8"),{"","","",""});
...
```

In case range is not found, 4 empty cells are made.

If you want to remove these cells too, you can wrap it around with query:

```
=Query( {all your ranges}, "select * where Col1 is not null")
```

This way you remove empty rows.